# How do I make this check for guild owner and administrator permissions?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that can only be operated by the owner or an admin of a server but the object I have is only checking for owner and not the admin perm, does anyone know how I can fix it to make it work how I intended it to?

```
if (interaction.user.id !== interaction.guild.ownerId || interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator)) {
  console.log(`[SYSTEM] Command failed cause non-admin ran the command - Command : set-verify  File: setverify.js`);
  return interaction.reply(`You do not have permission to use this command, are you an admin?`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've got the **PermissionsBitField** import

```js
import { PermissionsBitField } from 'discord.js';
```

And since you're going for an early return syntax your if statement should be:

```
if (interaction.user.id !== interaction.guild.ownerId && !interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator)) {
    return
}
```

That should let only the owner and administrators execute your interaction. The problem with your if statement was you were returning if either the interaction came from someone who was not the guild owner **OR** from an administrator.

Comment: Well thats how it's supposed to be, if the user isn't owner or admin the it should send the if statement. But the problem is in the test server i'm running the command on it's not checking for admin. If i switch to the owner account (i'm using two account to test) the command skips the if like it's supposed to and runs the command, but doesn't work for admin. If admin runs it it send the if and doesn't run the command like it should.

Comment: Did you apply the changes that I wrote? You should be using && not ||. Your original code doesn't run the command if it's an admin because of your condition. Basically your original code says "If the user is NOT THE OWNER OR THE USER IS AN ADMIN, return"